# Will Ads be shown in embedded youtube videos in 3rd party website?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, embed, ads

I'm trying to build a website, which will embed some youtube videos that I do not own.

**Given that I've already seen ads being shown when those videos were played on YouTube**, will ads be also shown if videos are embedded in 3rd website? I'm trying to show ads in the embedded videos but they were never played even if yellow spots (where ads are supposed to be played if it is being watched on Youtube) appear in the timeline of those embedded videos.

According to the Youtube Help doc:

> Ads appear on brand safe sites: YouTube works diligently so that our advertisers' brands appear on sites that reflect our respective core values. Our systems closely evaluate websites and their content against various factors when finding out whether to turn on In-stream ads on YouTube embeds. These factors include a strict set of guidelines on content like adult imagery, violence, inappropriate and hateful language, and sites that promote infringement.
> (https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/132596?hl=en)

I was wondering what makes a website brand safe. And as far as I've noticed, I've never seen ads played in embedded videos. Is it even possible to show ads on embedded videos?

Many thanks in advance.